# Is there a way to install custom folder icons?

Tags: icons, themes, home, folder

I have several folders in my home folder that are just plain blue icons, which I feel are a little out of place.

[image]

Is there an icon theme or tweak I can use to improve the look of my home folder a glance?

Comment: It might help a lot in productivity, Anyways Is there a tagging feature available?

Comment: @Tim well I need custom tags such as study programming and then I could search through them specifically

Comment: So that's one of the features they never thought of

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25480/discussion-between-aditya-ultra-and-tim).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is one trick, but is only relevant if you are using a small number of folders in the user's home directory. By default, in the home directory there is **Documents**, **Downloads**, **Music**, **Pictures**, **Public**, **Templates** and **Videos**. It's a set of default user directories, see the [freedesktop.org](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/) website for further information.

[image]

The idea is that you can replace your unwanted folders on the other, and give them the other icons. This is not exactly the right way, but it works.

I'll tell about it in my example:

I do not use **Public** and **Templates**, but I have folders **GitHub** and `Sports Interactive` and I would give them custom icons. To do this, I first edited the names of folders in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. It now looks like this:

```
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Sports Interactive"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/GitHub"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

After I posted custom icons in `.icons/elementary/places` (if you use a non-standard icon theme, the path will be different). The structure of the files in my case looks like this:

[image]

I took the icons from [FabianInostroza's DeviantArt](http://fabianinostroza.deviantart.com/art/Elementary-Extra-Folders-387250061). This is the largest repository of folder icons in the elementary OS style that I know of.

After I logged out and in again, my home folder looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I followed your instructions but the folders do not use the custom theme icons. Is it possible that the path `.icons/elementary/places` has changed recently?

Comment: orschiro, the folder has changed to `/usr/share/icons/elementary/`.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible at the moment. I reported this on launchpad at [Possibility to change folder icons](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1462824).

You can add a bounty on this if you want to have this feature as soon as possible.