# Can I add a folder icon to a custom folder?

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-files, icons, folder

The folders in 'Home' (e.g. Documents, Downloads, etc.) all have nice icons on their folders. I have a 'Google Drive' folder in my home area where I sync my files with Google Drive. I would like to change this folder icon.
I already tried to include icons in the elementary icon folder (/usr/share/elementary/places) and set the 'standard::icon' attribute of the folder via gio command. Unfortunately I get an error that says "gio: Setting attribute standard::icon not supported". I furthermore tried to set the attribute 'metadata::custom-icon' as explained [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/gio/). Yet this also did not change my folder icon.
I also found an [old post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/169/is-there-a-way-to-install-custom-folder-icons) where the icon was changed with some workaround. I would prefer a clean solution. Can someone explain me how I can achieve changing a folder icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an outstanding issue about this on Github here - https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/171

An attempt was made to implement custom overlays to folder icons but it was unsuccessful.  It would probably be easier to enable Files to honour a "custom-icon" metadata attribute but whether the UX team would want the user to completely change icons arbitrarily is another question.